# Inverse convention STM32

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I'm new to STM32, and I use STM32L476
I programmed a UART communication using CubeIDE, and I tried to use inverse convetion so the MSB will be first, instead the default convention which is the LSB first.
I configured the UART as the following:

```
static void UART_Init(void)
{
/* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_ENABLE();
    huart1.Instance = USART1;

    huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
    huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_EVEN;
    huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart1.AdvancedInit.MSBFirst = UART_ADVFEATURE_MSBFIRST_ENABLE;
    huart1.AdvancedInit.DataInvert = UART_ADVFEATURE_DATAINV_ENABLE;
    
if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        while(1);
    }
}
```

I using scope, and see that the data is transmitted in direct convention (LSB first).

Can someone help me, to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, we need to add the followingl line:

```
huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_MSBFIRST_INIT;
```

There is no need for the line:

```
huart1.AdvancedInit.DataInvert = UART_ADVFEATURE_DATAINV_ENABLE;
```

It works properly without it.